# Finite Krull dimension

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

If $A$ is a commutative ring and $n=\dim A$ is the Krull dimension of $A$.

There exists any criteria for we know that dimension de A is not infinite?

For example $A$ is a integral domain and integrally closed in $k=Frac(R)$ with any extra properties... then $\dim A$ es finite.

Thanks you all

Comment: It should suffice to assume that $A$ is finitely generated over a field (or a PID), which should cover a lot of examples of interest already (affine varieties and so forth).

Comment: Another large class is Noetherian local rings.